# Query Calendar Provider without Google account

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I know that Google Account that allows us to insert/update data to Calendar Provider wit it, But is it possible to use Calendar Provider WITHOUT Google Account ?, I mean can we query data in Calendar?

And can we use Calendar provider in SDK 8( Android 2.2 )

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a Google Account to query a local content provider. You can access data it exposes, as long as it does not require any special permissions. Did you try? If so, what error(s) did you get?